# Table column width Not Adjusted to content size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have added the Horizontal and Vertical Scrollbars in my table and I freezed the thread elements when I Scroll Vertically and i Freezed the tbody elements Upto Four Columns, but the table column width is not Adjusting to content size if a particular td content value is long.Need your Help to fix this.

[image: Click to View the Image In image i tried to increase the content length "WorchestershireWorchestershire" but the header is collapsed not adjusting to the content width]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/varLaG

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Town</th>
    <th>County</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Profession</th>
    <th>Anual Income</th>
    <th>Matital Status</th>
    <th>Children</th>
    <th>Anual Income</th>
    <th>Matital Status</th>
    <th>Children</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>Macelsfield</td>
    <td>Cheshire</td>
    <td>52</td>
    <td>Brewer</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jenny Jones</td>
    <td>Threlkeld</td>
    <td>Cumbria</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Shepherdess</td>
    <td>£28,000</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter Frampton</td>
    <td>Avebury</td>
    <td>Wiltshire</td>
    <td>57</td>
    <td>Musician</td>
    <td>£124,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Simon King</td>
    <td>Malvern</td>
    <td>Worchestershire</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>Naturalist</td>
    <td>£65,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
    <td>St Albans</td>
    <td>Hertfordshire</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>Pharmasist</td>
    <td>Retired</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
    <td>Edinburgh</td>
    <td>Lothian </td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>Vigilante</td>
    <td>£86,000</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td>Unknown</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
    <td>Bedford</td>
    <td>Bedfordshire</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>Housewife</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kat Dibble</td>
    <td>Manhattan</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>55</td>
    <td>Policewoman</td>
    <td>$36,000</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
    <td>Bolingbroke</td>
    <td>Lincolnshire</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Landowner</td>
    <td>Lots</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
    <td>Alderley</td>
    <td>Cheshire</td>
    <td>352</td>
    <td>Arcanist</td>
    <td>A pile of gems</td>
    <td>Single</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>£47,000</td>
    <td>Married</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

/***************End of HTML*****************/

```
table {
    position: relative;
    table-layout: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
  }



  thead {
     position: relative;
     display: block; 
     overflow: visible;
   }

   thead th {
      background-color: #99a;
      min-width: 120px;
      height: 32px;
      border: 1px solid #222;
   }

   thead th:nth-child(1) {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #88b;
   }

   thead th:nth-child(2) {
       position: relative;
       background-color: #88b;
   }

   thead th:nth-child(3) {
         position: relative;
         background-color: #88b;
   }

   thead th:nth-child(4) {
         position: relative;
         background-color: #88b;
   }


   tbody {
        position: relative;
        display: block; 
        height: 239px;
        overflow: scroll;
      }

   tbody td {
       background-color: #bbc;
       min-width: 120px;
       border: 1px solid #222;
   }

   tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  
        position: relative;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #99a;
   }

   tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {  
      position: relative;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #99a;
   }

   tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {  
         position: relative;
         height: 40px;
         background-color: #99a;
   }

   tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {  
         position: relative;
         height: 40px;
         background-color: #99a;
   }
```

/**********************End of Css**********************************/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { 

        $('thead').css("left", 
       -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
       $('thead th:nth- 
         child(1)').css("left", 
        $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
$('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
$('thead th:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
$('tbody td:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
$('thead th:nth-child(3)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
 $('tbody td:nth-child(3)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
 $('thead th:nth-child(4)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
 $('tbody td:nth-child(4)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); 
});
});
```

Comment: Try my answer below. It works.

Comment: Thanks for helping me VSM.Unfortunately the Content is getting Overlapped or Hided.Please check the Following Image link for your reference. 
Image Link-->     https://ibb.co/e9VcbK

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tbody').scroll(function(e) { //detect a scroll event on the tbody
   /*
    Setting the thead left value to the negative valule of tbody.scrollLeft will make it track the movement
    of the tbody element. Setting an elements left value to that of the tbody.scrollLeft left makes it maintain    it's relative position at the left of the table.    
    */
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the thead relative to the body scrolling
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first cell of the header
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the first column of tdbody
 $('thead th:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the second cell of the header
    $('tbody td:nth-child(2)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the second column of tdbody
 $('thead th:nth-child(3)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the third cell of the header
  $('tbody td:nth-child(3)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the third column of tdbody
  $('thead th:nth-child(4)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the third cell of the header
  $('tbody td:nth-child(4)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()); //fix the third column of tdbody
 
    
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  table-layout: auto;
  background-color: #aaa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
}


/*thead*/
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the header from the body allowing it to be positioned*/
  overflow: visible;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  max-width:120px;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {/*first cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88b;
}

thead th:nth-child(2) {/*second cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88b;
}

thead th:nth-child(3) {/*third cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88b;
}

thead th:nth-child(4) {/*third cell in the header*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88b;
}

/*tbody*/
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block; /*seperates the tbody from the header*/
  height: 239px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  max-width:120px;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {  /*the first cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {  /*the second cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {  /*the third cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {  /*the third cell in each tr*/
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #99a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Town</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
  <th>Anual Income</th>
        <th>Matital Status</th>
        <th>Children</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Macelsfield</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>52</td>
        <td>Brewer</td>
        <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny Jones</td>
        <td>Threlkeld</td>
        <td>Cumbria</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Shepherdess</td>
        <td>£28,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Frampton</td>
        <td>Avebury</td>
        <td>Wiltshire</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>Musician</td>
        <td>£124,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>4</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Simon King</td>
        <td>Malvern</td>
        <td>Worchestershire Wor chester shire</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Naturalist</td>
        <td>£65,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lucy Diamond</td>
        <td>St Albans</td>
        <td>Hertfordshire</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>Pharmasist</td>
        <td>Retired</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>3</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Austin Stevenson</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>Lothian </td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Vigilante</td>
        <td>£86,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>Unknown</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wilma Rubble</td>
        <td>Bedford</td>
        <td>Bedfordshire</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Housewife</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>1</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kat Dibble</td>
        <td>Manhattan</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>Policewoman</td>
        <td>$36,000</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>1</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Henry Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Bolingbroke</td>
        <td>Lincolnshire</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Landowner</td>
        <td>Lots</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>6</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alan Brisingamen</td>
        <td>Alderley</td>
        <td>Cheshire</td>
        <td>352</td>
        <td>Arcanist</td>
        <td>A pile of gems</td>
        <td>Single</td>
        <td>0</td>
  <td>£47,000</td>
        <td>Married</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try this code...

Updated css styles as below

```
tbody td {
  background-color: #bbc;
  min-width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  max-width:120px;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #99a;
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  max-width:120px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Helping me..But Still the Content is getting hided.Please Check the Image  https://ibb.co/gLvcbK

Comment: @DineshKumar, check this fiddle.text is wrapping when it is getting longer.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/g6pyjf24/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display: block` property on the thead and tbody.

The display property on the thead and tbody is responsible for that behaviour, you changed it to "block" which removes the tabular behaviour that you're after.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBrRjK

Comment: Thanks for Helping me Alexander.I need Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling Functionality for the above table

Comment: That's not a question to be answered, that's a how-to on an entire feature. I would recommend you use a pre-made solution for the table functionality you're after like: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html Alternatively if you do decide to build it all yourself you'll need to study tables in a little more detail to understand what you're working with.